# Converting an Objective-C block of code into Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios8

I'm failing to properly understand how to convert this into Swift notation. Could someone help me? I clearly need to improve my Objective-C understanding :(

```
// Setup coach marks
    NSArray *coachMarks = @[
        @{
            @"rect": [NSValue valueWithCGRect:(CGRect){{0,0},{45,45}}],
            @"caption": @"Helpful navigation menu"
        },
        @{
            @"rect": [NSValue valueWithCGRect:(CGRect){{10.0f,56.0f},{300.0f,56.0f}}],
            @"caption": @"Document your wedding by taking photos"
        }
];
```

I'm just not sure what [ {} ] means. An array in an array? it almost looks like JSON notation or something. What is this?

Thank you!

Comment: I would guess that is an object in an array, but I do not speak Objective C either.

Comment: It's an array containing 2 dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@[a,b]` is an Objective-C array literal with objects `a` and `b`.

`@{akey:avalue, bkey:bvalue}` is an Objective-C dictionary literal.

The `(CGRect){{0,0},{45,45}}` creates a CGRect. In Swift `CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: 45, height: 45))` would be the direct translation although there are shorter forms to do the same thing. As a struct this needs to be wrapped in an `NSValue` object to be put in an Objective-C collection.

Comment: I was happy to help with what is a fairly basic question because starting from the syntax it is hard to search without knowing the keyword "literal" (which combined with Objective-C would probably get you there). It is also fairly recent syntactic additions so won't be in slightly older Objective-C guides.